# Using license-restricted dependencies on cloudbees build

Tags: cloudbees

In order for my build to work under the Jenkins instance on DEV@Cloud I need 
to access the Oracle JDBC driver maven dependency, but that dependency 
cannot be found on standard Maven repositories due to copyright 
restrictions so our previous process was to manually install that 
dependency. Where and how can I install that dependency so that the Jenkins 
build can succeed?

Answer (score 1):

you can deploy this dependency to your release repository on cloudbees forge, that is added to your default maven settings for dependency resolution (so you don't have to change your pom.xml)

see http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/CloudBees+Private+Maven+Repository for details about deploying to this repository. Note: as maven3 don't include a WebDav connector, I suggest you mount your repository as a remote drive and run deploy:deploy-file with a file:// URL.